# how to get expected value from this

Tags: algorithm, math

this is Question(projecteuler 469 problem) and I just wnat to know how to get E(4) and E(6) step by step. Plz tell how to

In a room N chairs are placed around a round table.
Knights enter the room one by one and choose at random an available empty chair.
To have enough elbow room the knights always leave at least one empty chair between each other.
When there aren't any suitable chairs left, the fraction C of empty chairs is determined.
We also define E(N) as the expected value of C.
We can verify that E(4) = 1/2 and E(6) = 5/9.
Find E(1018). Give your answer rounded to fourteen decimal places in the form 0.abcdefghijklmn.

Comment: Looks like a Homework.

Comment: this is not homework ~!

Comment: Finding E(4) and E(6) is math, not programming, so you may want to try [math.se] (but show a little more work first - E(4) is simply "do you understand the question").  Finding E(1018) may be programming, but "tell me how step by step" is usually too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: This is a fun problem! I think to make an algorithm that will find E(1018) in a reasonable time, you'll have to not explore the whole tree, but process many symmetrical sub-trees as one.

Comment: Oh, that's not E(1018), but meant to be E(10^18). That project Euler thing is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the E(4) case, there are four chairs. The first knight comes in and sits in chair 0. The next knight comes in and the only place he can sit is chair 2, leaving chair 1 and chair 3 empty. No more knights can be seated. Regardless of where the first knight sits, the only space available to the next knight is at chair (first_knight + 2). The number of empty spaces will always be 2. So, 2/4 = 1/2.

In the E(6) case, you have chairs 0 through 5. Again, assume the first knight sits at chair 0. There are three possibilities for the second knight to sit: chairs 2, 3, or 4. If the second knight sits in chair 2, then the third knight can sit in chair 4. And if the second knight sits in chair 4, then the third knight can sit in chair 2. In both of those cases, the fraction of empty chairs is 1/2.

If the second knight sits in chair 3, then no more knights can be seated. The fraction of empty chairs is 2/3.

Add those possibilities together (1/2 + 1/2 + 2/3) and divide by 3. The result is 5/9.

Comment: thanks for what you sincere effort I can understand this problem.

Comment: @SanghwaJung: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Just click the checkmark there on the left of the answer.